# Azure Web Apps : How to access specific instance directly via URL?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have deployed our Sitecore CMS on to Azure Web Apps and having some indexing issues or similar. i.e. the updated changes is reflected for some users and not for all.

We have a scale turned on to 2.

I would like to troubleshoot by accessing the instance 1 and 2 directly via URL to make sure both instances have index built 100%.

How do I access each Azure Web Role instances directly via URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first step is to get the list of instance names. There is an Azure API for it, which you can easily invoke using Resource Explorer (https://resources.azure.com/). Use these steps:

- In Resource Explorer, find your Web App (in the tree or using search box)
- Under the app, click on Instances, which gives you an array of instances. Each instance has a long name like `622e6b27f9077701f23789e5e512844d22a7dfdd29261bc226f65cd000e2d94a`

Once you have the instance names, you can add a cookie in your requests to aim at a specific instance by setting the `ARRAffinity` cookie to that value. e.g.

```
ARRAffinity=622e6b27f9077701f23789e5e512844d22a7dfdd29261bc226f65cd000e2d94a
```

You can do it using a tool like `curl`. Or I like to use the EditThisCookie Chrome extension ([link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en)), which lets you set it from the browser.

In fact, you'll find that after hitting the page normally from the browser, you'll already get an `ARRAffinity`, as it's used for session stickiness. But the Chrome extension lets you change it and aim at other instances.

See also related blog post: http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/03/access-specific-instance/

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to either FTP or view the physical files on each instances? Or each of these instances have common shared physical folder  Or we FTP to one central location which gets replicated to instances?

Comment: It's a shared folder, so Instances don't matter.

Comment: So my take is that if we have 3 instances MVC website they all share the common folder which hosts DLLs?  Your answer contracts with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629623/clarification-on-azure-web-app-scale-instance/34654102#34654102 where Brij has mentioned that changes will be continuously deployed to each VMs.

Comment: Also  I managed to use your trick to access the site hosted on each instance. Is it also possible to FTP to specific instance and view the physical folders and files.

Comment: All instances share the same files (even if that other answer implies otherwise!). FTP happens on a VM that is not any of your instances, so it is completely instance agnostic. So the need to aim FTP at a specific instance just does not arise.

Comment: What happens when your ARRAffinity value is incorrect - i.e. beceause the instance got scaled down? Does it keep going to a random server until you set a different cookie?

Comment: Is there any way to get the instance just by using an URL? I want to access them from Prometheus Job and it doens't support cookies, only URL