# How to get access to azure app service instances directly via specific URL?

Tags: azure, caching, azure-web-app-service, load-balancing, azure-traffic-manager

I have an Asp.Net MVC big e-learning site app that is hosted on azure(app service) with 10 instances. 
We disabled ARR Affinity to improve performance and enabled traffic manager also.

Now I want to clear cache in every instance so how can I make a request for a specific instance? or is there any way we can clear cache using some receiver/messaging system?

If I enable ARR Affinity then I can make a request using a cookie.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Web Apps : How to access specific instance directly via URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833120/azure-web-apps-how-to-access-specific-instance-directly-via-url)

Comment: No, Because  ARR Affinity is disabled for my case.

Comment: I also have a similar need and ARR is not enabled - does anyone know of a solution when ARR is disabled?